# Google Maps Javascript API access GeoJSON feature property explicitly

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geojson

I've been working with the Google Maps Javascript API for several weeks now. I've been having trouble accessing a property of a geoJSON after it has been added to the map and becomes a feature of the map.

For example, lets say I have this sample geoJSON

```
var geo = {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[
              {"type":"Feature","id":"country","properties":
                  {"name":"ExampleCountry"},"geometry":  {exampleGeometry}}
          ]};
```

Lets say I load the geoJSON and want to access the id property of the feature I have just added. Neither `feature.id` nor `feature.getProperty('id')` works in this case. From debugging, I found out that I can access the 'id' property via `feature.F`. That solution was working fine for several weeks, but for whatever reason, last week it ceased to work. I instead have to use `feature.K` to access the ID property.

```
var mapOptions = {
      center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 8
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {mapOptions});

 map.data.loadGeoJson(geo);
 map.data.forEach(function(feature) {
     //Used to Work, randomly stopped working last week (feature.F is undefined)
     var id = feature.F;
     //New Solution
     var id = feature.K;
 });
```

This doesn't seem to be a permanent solution. Does anyone have any idea how this could have happened?

Comment: **Do not use undocumented properties of the API, they can and do change with every release**. Use the documented functions.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: What would you propose instead?

Comment: Reading the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Data.Feature): `feature.getId()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The id of a feature is not a "property" in the meaning of geoJSON.

There is a getter-method for the `id` of a `feature`, use:

```
 feature.getId()//should return 'country'
```

When you want to get a property(stored in the properties-member) use e.g.

```
 feature.getProperty('name')//should return 'ExampleCountry'
```